# Differece between Static and reinerpret cast

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

```
class b
{
}
class d :public b
{
}

int main
{
 d* d_p = new d();
 b* b_p = static_cast<base*>(d_p);

 b* b_p = reinterpret_cast<base*>(d_p); // any difference will it make
 return 0;
}
```

So in the above example does static and reinterpret cast make any difference functionaly etc..? for me both are same in this scenario.

Comment: There is no difference in the sense that your program wouldn't compile regardless of which cast you prefer in this erroneous code :P

Comment: I have edited the code if you think it gives error due to return type. i just wrote the code here directly just to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be a difference. You should check [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t280611-reinterpret_cast-v-static_cast.html)

Comment: I went through the link and found the below explaination for same example which i mentioned- Derived d; BaseB* bp = static_cast<BaseB*>(&d); // valid: bp now points to BaseB subobject of d BaseB* rp = reinterpret_cast<BaseB*>(&d); // probably not valid, could result in rp pointing at // the BaseA memory in d but with the BaseB* type. But here i am not fully convinced. can you please explain...

Comment: I know the basic difference between these two. But my question is that in the my example does it make any any difference?